# Homogeneity of BS Formula

Tags: options, black-scholes

I'm reading M. S. Joshi's paper "Log-Type Models, Homogeneity of Option Prices and Convexity", and I'm having problem understanding equation 1:

$$
C(S_0, K) = \int (S - K)_+ \Phi\left(\frac{S}{S_0}\right)\frac{dS}{S}
$$

Could anyone help? I can only write down

$$
C(S_0, K) = \int (S - K)_+ \phi(Z)dZ
$$
where $S = S_0 e^{(r-\frac12\sigma^2)t - \sigma \sqrt{t}Z}$ and $Z$ being the standard normal random variable, but I don't see the connection here.

Comment: There is nothing to understand in the sense that what Joshi is saying is that if the density of $\log S_T/S_t$ is of the form $\Phi (\log S_T/S_t)$ or equivalently $\tilde\Phi(S_T/S_t)$ then the claim price is homogeneous of degree 1.